# url-rewrite & how to set it up with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I just got the rewrite engine loaded and active but can't figure out
how to design a good .htaccess file.
I want to transform links like this :

```
http://localhost/index.php?u=username --> http://localhost/username/
http://localhost/index.php?id=1&v=2 --> http://locahost/1x2
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean users will enter the longer URLs (on the left) that get shortened (as shown on the right)?

Comment: i mean users enter the shorter urls ofcourse on the right

Comment: And should the URL in the address bar stay "localhost/username" or change to "index.php?u=username" on rewrite?

Comment: the url should stay locahost/username/ i mean you know myspace? exact the same myspace.com/someuser/

Comment: Testing on Apache.. please wait! :)

Comment: Are `id` and `v` always going to be nums? If not then how do you want usernames that contain `x` to be handled?

Comment: id and v are always nums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Rewriting to change:

> ht*p://localhost/username/ -- ending with / is optional
>     to > ht*p://localhost/index.php?u=username
>
> ht*p://localhost/1x2 -- case-insensitive (matches 4X4)
>     to > ht*p://localhost/index.php?id=1&v=2

**.htaccess** content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/\d]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?u=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d+)x(\d+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=%1&v=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for my vague questions i am bad with regex.
Thank you, Ravi for this brilliant job - that did the trick :)

Comment: iam new i think not.When its possible i come back to vote if its possible